# How i can do roman, alphabetic list in css

Tags: css

For example, i can do this lists:

```
<ol type="a", type="i", type="I"></ol>
```

How i can do similar list not using html `type` attribute. And `type` attribute is good practice to using in css3? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do it with the [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) CSS setting.

```
list-style-type: lower-roman/upper-roman
```

---

From the documentation:

> ## Summary
>
> The list-style-type CSS property specifies appearance of a list item
>   element. As it is the only one who defaults to display:list-item, this
>   is usually a `<li>` element, but can be any element with this display
>   value.
>
> The color of the marker will be the same as the computed color of the
>   element it applies to.
>
> ## Syntax
>
> Formal syntax: disc | circle | square | decimal | decimal-leading-zero
>   | **lower-roman** | **upper-roman** | lower-greek | lower-latin | upper-latin
>   | armenian | georgian | lower-alpha | upper-alpha | none

---

The [W3C HTML 5 Reference of the `<ol`> tag](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/ol.html#ol.attrs.type) allows to use the inline `type` attribute:

> The type attribute on the ol element was deprecated in a previous
>   version of HTML, **but is no longer deprecated**, as it has meaning and is
>   not simply presentational.

Comment: I don't think using the `type` attribute is a good practice. Design settings should remain in the CSS files, not the HTML ones.

Comment: Okay, thanks. My editor not accept type in html. But it work in browser

Comment: @ArthurYakovlev See my edit for further info. Now it's clear why your editor doesn't accept this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS `list-style-type` property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type